# Combining Cauchy Integral Formula and Taylor Series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, cauchy-integral-formula

We know that if $f(z)$ is analytic at $a \in \mathbb{C}$, then by Taylor,

$$f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(z-a)^n$$

By Cauchy, we also know that

$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i } \int_C \frac{f(s)}{(s-a)^{n+1}} \, ds$$

Combining these two, I'm imagining that it would then follow that

$$f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(s-a)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{n!}{2 \pi i } \int_C \frac{f(s)}{(s-a)^{n+1}} \hspace{0.1cm} ds}{n!}(z-a)^n $$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 \pi i } \left[\int_C \frac{f(s)}{(s-a)^{n+1}}  \hspace{0.1cm} ds \right] (z-a)^n $$

I've become very familiar with Taylor series and Cauchy's integral formula as separate understandings, but I've never seen anyone combine both of the results. Wouldn't this be a representation of the Taylor formula that
complex analysis textbooks should include as a direct corollary of both Taylor and Cauchy Integral Formula? Why haven't I seen these two popular tools combined in this manner? Perhaps I have made an error?

Comment: Making the $dz$ in the final term "glued" to $(z-a)^n$ is no good idea. Also, using the same parameter, $z$, in the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$, and in the integral over $C$ is not good at all. Just isolate the coefficients as integrals, this should be enough. As it stays, the last formula is not useful...

Comment: OK, now after the many edits in the allowed five minutes after post, we finally have parentheses around the integral, this is good. The same $z$ used at all places is but (for my taste) still irritating. Outside, on the L.H.S. it is a constant...

Comment: @dan_fulea I have edited the post so that the use of the same parameter $z$ has now changed to $z$ and $s$ where appropriate. It sounds like the formulation of $f$ I've given is correct, but unhelpful

Comment: This looks to me like a special case of the development of Laurent series which is quite common in complex analysis texts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now everything is fine! The formula is correct, but it is in some sense tautological. (We start with an expansion, extract/isolate the coefficient by using the residue theorem, and put it back as an integral in the expansion.) The question is but as it is a question, and has to be respected! I do it, making steps on own feet is always a good idea in a new field, asking questions may help to get the essence in short time! Yes, this formula is not very helpful...

Comment: How many times have you seen this formula? $$a\left(\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2+b\left(\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)+c=0$$

Comment: The Taylor formula for complex differentiable functions is commonly derived from Cauchy's formula, which provides an integral representation for the coefficients mentioned in your question. This derivation also offers insights into the region of convergence of the Taylor series. See http://mathonline.wikidot.com/taylor-s-theorem-for-analytic-complex-functions for instance.

Comment: @Gary Wow it's nice to see that the gap has been bridged!